# 使用中のSQLite3データベースを別のホストへバックアップするには？

Tags: sqlite

使用中のSQLite3データベースは、次の方法でバックアップできますね（オンラインバックアップ）

```
sqlite3 /path/to/db ".backup /path/to/backup"
```

しかしデータベースが大きいので、この方法ではディスク容量が足りません。

そこでローカルにファイルを作らずに、別のホストへバックアップを送りたいのですが、なにかいい方法がないものでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rdiff-backupでディレクトリの差分を同期する方法もあるようです。

```
aptitude install rdiff-backup
(exclusiveロックを取る)
rdiff-backup local_var user@host::/remote_var
(ロックを解放)
```

Comment: 手前味噌で少し試しただけですが、今のところこれが最も簡単で良いです。

Comment: どのみちrdiff中はサービスが止まるけれども、差分のほうがマシという考えです。ロックはexclusiveよりもsharedのほうが良さそう

Answer (score 2):

NFSを使って、別のホストのディレクトリもしくはファイルをマウントし、そのマウントした先を出力先に指定すれば、ローカルファイルではなく、別のホストのファイルにバックアップされます。

Answer (score 0):

データベースが大きすぎてバックアップが取れないということであれば、アプリケーションを停止してファイルをコピーするのが確実で一番速い方法だと思います。

一応、

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite3 ".dump" | ssh remotehost 'cat > a'
```

といったようにダンプを標準出力経由でリモートに転送する方法も考えられますが、DBが大きいのであれば

- アプリケーションの動作が遅延する
- バックアップに長時間かかる
- またはその両方

といった事態が起きることが想像されます。

(そもそもバックアップも取れないほどストレージが逼迫してること自体をどうにかすべきですが)

Comment: もしも使用中ではないDBをバックアップするならば、これは1つのよい方法ですね。他にSCPがありますね。

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite3 store.db ".backup /dev/stdout" > backup.db
```

標準出力のリダイレクト先はなんとでも。(httpのレスポンスでもいい)

Comment: ありがとうございます。  
httpのレスポンス（にリダイレクトして標準出力をブラウザでダウンロードする？）の詳しい方法を教えて頂けませんか。  
それから、これはエラーです。  

    `sqlite3 source.db ".backup /dev/stdout"`
    Error: cannot open "/dev/stdout"

もちろんこれは別にできなくていいのですが（`echo hello | /dev/stdout` のように内容が端末に表示されても良さそうなものですが）

./backup.db以外の他の場所へ出力するためにパイプをしても、このエラーが起きてしまいます。

  `sqlite3 source.db ".backup /dev/stdout" | ssh ... "cat > backup.db"`

なぜ/dev/stdoutを開けないのか分からずに困っています。

Comment: /dev/stdoutが使えるかどうかはホストOSに依存しますー。

Comment: @rakou1986 Linux の様な `/dev/stdout` が使える OS 上でも同じエラーになります。sqlite3 のソースコードを眺めてみると、出力先がパイプ(FIFO)だとダメみたいです。

Comment: `/dev/stdout`はありますが、だめでした。コードを見てくださりありがとうございます。